# JavaScript add code to an already set event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I try to add new code to an already set event and don't know how to do it without writing the code again?

As you can see I have an `onComplete` event which throws an `alert()` after finishing the Flash file. Now I additionally want to open an jQuery Dialog. How can I do that?

```
<html><head><title>testAddEvent</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="filesOthersForTesting/jquery-1.x.x.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="filesFromJWPlayer/jwplayer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            jwplayer('playerDiv-1').setup({
                flashplayer: 'filesFromJWPlayer/player.swf',
                file: 'sampleContent/bla.flv',
                provider: 'video',
                height: 300,
                width: 300,
                stretching: 'uniform',
                events: {
                    onComplete: function() {
                        alert('Complete!');
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
<body>
    <div id="playerDiv-1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Update 1:** 
This code is an example. `alert()` is an example for a bunch of lines. The question in general is, could I add something to an already initialized event (`events.onComplete`).

Something like: `events.onComplete = events.onComplete + 'new code here';` for parameters.

@Pointy: Yes jQuery 1.3.2 is old, switched to x ;).

Comment: Call the dialog instead of an alert? lol

Comment: Your question is not clear; specifically, you haven't explained why the obvious solution of simply typing more code into the event handler won't work for you.

Comment: also: jquery 1.3.2 is **ancient**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function decorateBefore(target, decorator) {
    var fn = function () {
        decorator.apply(this, arguments);
        return target.apply(this, arguments);
    };
    // fix inheritance if it's constructor 
    // (it's not needed in your case)
    fn.prototype = target.prototype;
    return fn;
}    

someObj.onComplete = decorateBefore(someObj.onComplete, function(){
  // my code here
  // this function will accept same arguments as original, it's return value will be ignored
})
```

Comment: That looks good. Is it something similar to the following code in Java:

`public overide nameFunction() { super(); // new code here ... } `